# Pointing requests for a site to my localhost with specific port number with Fiddler

Tags: web, fiddler

I'm trying to redirect all requests for my site to my localhost with port number. So I tried this:

```
if (oSession.host=="request.mysite.com") {
    oSession.host="000.000.000.000:8080/MySite";
}
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

`[Fiddler] HTTP Request specified an invalid port number.`

I have Tomcat server, running Windows 8.1, and I connect to my localhost with 8080 port number. I also tried it this way:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs=="request.mysite.com") {
    oSession.hostname="000.000.000.000:8080/MySite";
}
```

In this case there was no error, but also no pointing to my localhost. I tried to use my machine name instead of the IP, tried to write localhost, but nothing worked as expected.

Another attempt was to use Host Remapping tool in Fiddler. I wrote this:

```
000.000.000.000:8080/MySite request.mysite.com
```

But got this error message when tried to save:

[image]

I don't know why none of this works... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a URLPath `/MySite` in anything that expects a `Host`; a Host, by definition, doesn't include the path.

If you need to inject a new path component, you can't use the Hosts extension and you must adjust your FiddlerScript to change the host *and* prepend the target string to the `PathAndQuery`.

`HostnameIs` is a method, not a property.

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("request.mysite.com") && 
    !oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")) 
{
    oSession.host="0.0.0.0:8080";
    oSession.PathAndQuery = "/MySite" + oSession.PathAndQuery;
}
```